# Speeding up Steve's Carts 2 assembly time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I am messing around with Steve's Carts 2 in creative mode, to test things for Survival Mode in Tekkit.

I don't really want to be waiting 8 hours for a cart to be build, especially considering it is a single player world.

Is there any way I can speed up the cart assembly process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an item called "Upgrade: Creative Mode" and it is only spawn-able in creative mode. You can spawn one of these and hold "shift + right click" on the assembly machine and this will make all carts assemble almost instantly.